# Workaround LastPass "This request is taking longer than normal."

Tags: lastpass

On occasion when I try to create a new site or update an existing one, I get the message "ERROR: Sorry, this request is taking longer than normal."

[image]

The issue seems to last several hours at a time and is not alleviated by connecting to different WiFi networks or restarting my browser.

Since I'm a Premium member I've submitted a help ticket for this issue and the response I got was:

> We've tested this on our end and can't replicate the issue.
>   We've released a patch to fix this issue. Uninstall and reinstall the plugin.

Kind of self-contradictory, but whatever. Reinstalling resolves the problem but is too nuclear for my taste, it takes too long and wipes out any preferences I had saved.

Has anybody else seen this, and you do you know any method of resolving it that is quicker than reinstalling LastPass entirely?

Browser: Firefox Quantum 61.0.1

Comment: Which browser are you using?  I have run into this in the past (with FF), but not lately. I think it had to do with a connectivity issue on their end.

Comment: In meantime, methods to try instead of installing/reinstalling 1. Disabling/enabling the extension 2. Deleting cookies/cache.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue after a recent update (Jan 2020). Disabling didn't work,  I also had to uninstall and re-install the plug-in for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I've fixed this in the past by logging out of LastPass and then back in again via the extension.